# What is the Dojo equivalent of jQuery's scope attribute?

Tags: jquery, dojo, scope

In jQuery, a DOM node or jQuery object can be passed as an attribute in a query, which sets the scope:

```
var myScope = $('#someDiv');
$('a',myScope).addClass('red');
$('li',myScope).css('display','inline');
```

Now, in Dojo I can chain several `.query()`s after each other, but what should I do if I have a certain DOM node - not a nodeList - that I want to use as a scope?

KTHNX

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just like jQuery. The `query()` method has an additional parameter which can be used as scope:

```
dojo.query("#someDiv", scope)
```

Where `scope` can be an element ID or a DOM node.

For further information have a look at the [Dojo API documentation](http://api.dojotoolkit.org/jsdoc/1.3.2/dojo.query).

Comment: Super, thanks! I had looked at .query() on docs.dojocampus.org and missed the section that mentions the scope.